# Why do i need to create an object, any advantage here ng-controller="InvoiceController as invoice"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oop

as i am in learning stage of angularjs i am tring to understand each and every thing, so here is a some doubt, that i would like to ask.
Consider the code:

```
<div ng-controller="InvoiceController as invoice">
<b>Invoice:</b>
<div>
   Quantity: <input type="number" ng-model="invoice.qty" required >
</div>
<div>
   Costs: <input type="number" ng-model="invoice.cost" required >
   <select ng-model="invoice.inCurr">
      <option ng-repeat="c in invoice.currencies">{{c}}</option>
   </select>
</div>
....
</div>
```

Since, angular is javascript code which runs on user browser, So it really required to create an instance of a controller and then with the object we have to handle.

```
<div ng-controller="InvoiceController as invoice">
..
```

**`invoice.qty`** etc...

Hope you have understood, what i am tring to ask.
All i need to know is, by doing this kind of object creation (object oriented), do we get any advantage in client side programming language.

reference : http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#model in "Adding UI logic: Controllers" section

Comment: I've never seen that syntax for controller declaration, why not just `ng-controller="InvoiceController"`?

Comment: @tymeJV, Yes, i also, seen this first time, so only showed interest and posted here. refer: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#model
in "Adding UI logic: Controllers" section